# Setting windows root view controller not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to change the view controller from my AppDelegate like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
NSLog(@"ViewController: %@",vc);
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
NSLog(@"ViewController: %@",self.window.rootViewController);
```

However the screen remains black. Here are my NSLogs:

```
ViewController: MyViewController
ViewController: (null)
```

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"window: %@",self.window);` to check window also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems your `self.window` is nil. Are you sure you did not forget to create it?

```
self.window = [ [ UIWindow alloc ] initWithFrame:[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ] ];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the root view controller from storyboard without writing any code by dragging the arrow to the ViewController that you want:
[image]